# Can I use asp FileUpload to select a folder?

Tags: html, asp.net, file, input, types

I need something like the FileUpload control in asp.net that will allow the user to browse for a folder and enter a file name of a new file to upload.

From what I've seen FileUpload requires a file to be selected. It seems that html input type="file" has the same requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: no it is a file upload not folder upload.

Comment: anything similar that will solve my problem? basically i need a simple browse button that allows them to select the folder and enter the name for themselves then i can display the full path/file name in the usual text box...

Comment: i don't think something like that exists (at-least i don't know of any), but you can try this http://ajaxuploader.com/demo/upload-folders.aspx which is very close to what you may want. *Warning:* no guarantee it may work on all browsers. Another way is you can write an activeX, flash or java component, which user may have to trust. anyhow the task is not going to be an easy one.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting an entire folder is not possible in FileUploadControl as it is meant for a single file. Although you can have a Multi File Selection. [Multiple File Upload User Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24271/Multiple-File-Upload-User-Control)

Answer (score 0):

C# has build-in FTPrequest class where you can create folders, upload files, delete files etc.

If you want to upload folders from a webpage, you cannot use this technology in the browser, then you will have to use a rich-client such as Java, Flash or similar plugin.

If you can provide the users with a Windows or Mac client, you can use C# (either .NET or Mono) for the FTP transfer.

ZIP files arent a problem for ASP.net nor C#, but you still only upload 1 file (zip-archive) and then its up to the server to unzip it using eg. C#. Look at 7-Zip which is opensource, then you might get some ideas too.

You could also just try and use the build-in lib for it (compression):

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/csharp/2/10050636/how-to-compress-and-decompress-file-in-c.aspx

or try this link...

http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iu7/uploading-folders-in-aspnet.htm

Comment: Thanks Rony. Thing is - I don't want to upload anything. I just want them to be able to use a typical 'browse' type feature to be able to select the location for a file that will be created later. Sounds like it should be really easy but I'm fairly new to this...